# .htaccess redirect from GET variable to url string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I need to redirect

```
/search?keywords=somesearchterm
```

to

```
/search/somesearchterm
```

This seems incredibly basic but I've been pounding my head against it for an hour.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to implement what is called a "301 Redirect" with mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/search\?keywords=somesearchterm$ /search/somesearchterm
```

adding regular expressions:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/search\?keywords=(.+) /search/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`R=301` means provide a 301 Header redirect so the user's URL changes in the browser, and `L` means don't process any more rewrite rules if this one matches.

---

If you want to do the reverse -- in other words, if someone goes to `mysite.com/search/asearchterm` and you want the URL to stay the same, but "behind the scenes" you want it to load a certain server script, do this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/search/(.+) /search.php\?keywords=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not match aginst Query string in RewriteRule directive. Use %{THE_REQUEST}  or %{QUERY_STRING} server variables to match the Query string :

The following rule works fine for this redirection

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/search\?kewords=([^&\s]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [NE,NC,R,L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /search?keyword=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```